Draw a square in the middle and bottom than the Bounding Box Finder
Hello everyone I have a problem. I have a document whose sheets are horizontally oriented. Using Fender's Bounding Box, I find the borders of the text on the page. Next, I need to draw a square (text inside it: Done), which is located at the bottom of the text border and exactly in the middle.
I'm trying to flip the PDPageContentStream using Matrix
float pageWidth = lastPage.getCropBox().getWidth(); //595.0

BoundingBoxFinder boxFinder = new BoundingBoxFinder(lastPage);
boxFinder.processPage(lastPage);
Rectangle2D box = boxFinder.getBoundingBox();

PDPageContentStream canvas = new PDPageContentStream(document, lastPage, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true)

//before the transformation using Matrix
canvas.setStrokingColor(Color.GREEN);
canvas.addRect((float) box.getMinX(), (float) box.getMinY(), (float) box.getWidth(), (float) box.getHeight());
canvas.stroke();

Matrix matrix = Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90), 0, 0);
matrix.translate(0, -pageWidth);
canvas.transform(matrix);

//Other code
...
canvas.setStrokingColor(Color.RED);
canvas.addRect((float) box.getMinX(), (float) box.getMinY(), (float) box.getWidth(), (float) box.getHeight());
canvas.stroke();

How is it really

How it should be

But for some reason, the green frame (this is the processing after BoundingBoxFinder) highlights the text correctly, but the red one (this is the processing of working with Matrix) highlights the text incorrectly. I thought that the lower-left corner of the green frame should coincide with the lower-left corner of the red frame, the left sides should also coincide, but for some reason this does not happen (
For vertical orientation, the frame is being drawn successfully (I get the coordinates of the lower left corner of the frame, calculate the middle of the page and get the coordinates I need)
Please tell me where I am wrong(

I'm sorry if the code is not enough, I'll be happy to add more if needed.


I don't understand why you think the rotation of the lower left of the rectangle of the bounding box should remain the same after transformation; after all, the transformation is completely independent from the bounding box. Also I don't understand where exactly you expect the red box to be, could you clarify?

@mkl, I need the lower-left corner of the red rectangle to be equal to the lower-left corner of the green rectangle (i.e. the lower-left corner of the red rectangle should be where the text ends - I indicated with an arrow and where the left border of the text is)

@mkl If in general I need to get the coordinates of the lower-left corner where the text ends after transformations using Matrix by 90 degrees.  I'm sorry if I didn't explain it well.
